# Cannot connect to SQL Server - what's wrong?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express Management Studio with Service Pack 1 32/64 bit.

When I try to connect I get the following error:

[image]

Have I installed/done something wrong? Because I cannot see anything in SQL Server Services:

[image]

Please, help me, I really do not know what to do with it.

Comment: You installed management studio. Have you installed an sql server to connect to?

Comment: You've most likely only installed the **Management Studio** - only the management GUI - but **NOT** the actual SQL Server **database engine**! What file did you download & install? See [Scott Hanselman's web page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSqlServerExpress.aspx) with lots of links to download the **SQL Server Express with Tools** version - database engine & management studio

Comment: This question should not be tagged with `sql`

Comment: Thank you both so much! I have already visited Scott Hanselman's web page and downloaded&installed SQL Server 2012 Express x64. It worked! I am very grateful for your help.